# html2canvas Chart.js chart not rendered

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, html2canvas, todataurl

I am trying to export a div that contains a Chart.js chart as an Iamge. All elements are displayed perfectly fine, however, the Chart.js canvas just doesn't get rendered.

I am calling my export function in the callback of the onAnimationComplete option in my chart, so the export can't happen before the chart is fully built.

Here is how my html2canvas and download functions look:

```
download() {
        this.dl.download = this.fileName;
        this.dl.click();
}

loadDataUrl($node) {
    this.hideUnwantedElements();
    html2canvas($node, {
        background: '#ffffff',
        scale: 4,
        proxy: 'proxy-for-cors-images',
        onrendered: (canvas) => {
            this.showElements();
            this.dl.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }});
}
```

Can anyone tell me if it is even possible to export Chart.js charts with html2canvas and if so, how? 
I also tried the toDataURL() function on the chart canvas but it only returns the data URL for a tranparent png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes!** It is possible to export *(save as image)* chart *(created with ChartJS)* using html2canvas.

**HERE IS HOW :**

```js
var isChartRendered = false;

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false
      }]
   },
   options: {
      // setting following option is mandatory
      animation: {
         onComplete: function() {
            isChartRendered = true
         }
      }
   }
});

function download() {
   if (!isChartRendered) return; // return if chart not rendered
   html2canvas(document.getElementById('chart-container'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
         var link = document.createElement('a');
         link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
         link.download = 'myChart.jpeg';
         link.click();
      }
   })
}
```

```css
#chart-container { background: white }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="download()">save chart as...</button>
<div id="chart-container">
   <canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
</div>
```

<sub>**PS:** Needless to say but obviously, this is just an example, you need to adopt this accordingly to your project.</sub>

Comment: thanks a lot for that example
I tried using it in my project but it still does not render the canvas.
I also made a console.log in the onComplete callack and it appears in the console before the animation is complete. Is this normal?

Comment: no, it isn't. which version of chartjs are you using? make sure to use the latest one - 2.6.0

Comment: Chart.js version 2.6.0

Comment: then, maybe you're not creating the chart correctly. there's no way onComplete function will run before animation completes. perhaps, double check everything...

Comment: I now managed to get the canvas redered by adding a setTimeout to the onComplete callback.
However, this is in no way a beutiful solution for my problem and I can't really get behind why my onComplete fires too early..

Comment: this is not working on ie 11 version. what can be the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that anyone else has the same problem with the onComplete callback firing too early in Chart.js, here's how I was able to fix it without adding a setTimeout:

This is the correct way to load my export data after the animation is completed

```
animation: {
   onComplete: () => {
   this.loadExportElements();
   }
}
```

My first approach looked like this and did not work:

```
animation: {
                onComplete: this.loadExportElements()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onRendered is now deprecated

// we are targeting the legend and waiting for the promise to complete, you can skip this part if you dont want the legend to apear

```
html2canvas($("#yourChartID").find("ul")[0]).then(grid1Legend => {

   var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a3');
  var chart1 = $("#yourChartID").get(0).toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
  var grid1LegendtoUrl = grid1Legend.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
  pdf.text(675, 275,"my chart");
  pdf.addImage(chart1, 'JPEG', 590, 325);
  pdf.addImage(grid1LegendtoUrl, 'JPEG', 465, 475);
  pdf.save("state_summary.pdf");



});
```

basically html2canvas will not save your canvas , what you can do is to point htmltocanvas to the canvas chart (chart.js) by using get(0) this will capture the chart then manually add the legend and the title as shown above and setting the correct cordinates.