# How to export chart js as image using jquery

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I want to download chart to image. 
I tried by giving the below code, but it was downloaded as

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXEop.jpg

```
     $("#btnExport").click(function() {
          html2canvas($('#canvas'),{
             onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var a =document.getElementById("down");
                    a.setAttribute('href',canvas.toDataURL("image/png") );
                    a.setAttribute('download', 'download.png');
                    a.click();
                }
           });
        });
```

But i want to download like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ONGa.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html2canvas Chart.js chart not rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979710/html2canvas-chart-js-chart-not-rendered)

Comment: here is the reproduction in form of fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s49nzvg3/